# Linux - grub prompt appears on booting the system

Tags: linux, grub

I was trying to install HELiOS in a system during which system was shut down forcefully,

Now when i try to boot all i get is,

```
grub>
```

As some sites suggest recovery using `set` command. I am not able to do that as well because it shows "Error 27:Unrecognized command"

I want to start install OS fresh .Please let me know how to proceed from this.

I get this error as well : 
**/boot/grub/stage1 exists... no**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you want a fresh install, preserving no data, just start the installation again and make sure there are no more forced shutdowns.

It looks like GRUB hasn't been written correctly to your drive, so rather than trying to resolve the GRUB issue, just start over.

Comment: As you said i tried it and it didnt work with the some version of OS but when i tried with latest version it worked..